# Create Users and Roles using Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, roles

I used this code to create default Users and Roles in the Startup file.

```
public void CreateDefaultRolesAndUsers()
    {
          var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(db));
          var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
          IdentityRole role = new IdentityRole();
          if(!roleManager.RoleExists("Admins"))
          {
              role.Name = "Admins";
              roleManager.Create(role);

              ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();
              user.UserName = "Ahmed";
              user.Email = "ahmed@live.com";
              var Check = userManager.Create(user, "Ahmed*90");
              if(Check.Succeeded)
              {
                   userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admins");
              }
          }
    }
```

The Role is created but the User does not ..where is the problem??

Comment: Is `Check.Succeeded` true?  If not, what other information is on `Check`?

Comment: What the error you received, or the information you got when you tried debugging your code?